# How to route to specific div in a component in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

My routes for the application are

```
const router = new VueRouter({
mode:'history',
routes:[
    {
        path:'/home',
        name:'home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/services',
        name: 'services',
        component: Services
    },
    {
        path:'/blogs',
        name:'blogs',
        component:Blogs
    },
    {
        path:'/pingme',
        name:'pingme',
        component:Pingme
    }
],
```

})

Now, in services route I want to navigate to the  which is present in the Home component. How can I create router so as to navigate to the services div when the services link is clicked?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to route to specific div in /home component from /services route?

Comment: Do you mean, how to use the [router link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/)?

Comment: Yes Jayesh Dhandha exactly

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to bring in focus to a specific div in the `Service` component.

we will make use of query params to achive this. You add add a dedicated url as well which will do this.

This is my route:

```
{
    path: '/services',
    name: 'services',
    component: Services
}
```

Then in the url `localhost:8000/services?show=mydiv` and in the mounted hook of the component do something like this:

```
mounted() {
  // add a id to the div we want to bring in foucs
  // and id and the id is paased the query params
  document.getElementById(this.$route.query.show).scrollIntoView()
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

> Edit

Another way we can make this work is by using a watcher and a computed property.

First add a computed property for the show query param in the route.

```
computed: {
  show() { return this.$router.query.show }
}
```

Then add a watcher to trigger the focus.

```
watch: {
  show: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(value) { 
      document.getElementById(value).scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

That should work in all cases.

Comment: yes, it is working. But the new problem arises. When I am in pingme component, I am able to move to services section in Home component, but when I am in home component and I click services link nothing happens.

Comment: Nothing happens as in it is not redirected or the div is not focused?

Comment: Div is not focussed

Comment: I got it so we might want to use a watcher instead. Updating my answer above.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Please if you share some solution highly appreciated